# Parsing nested JSON with Pentaho

Tags: json, parsing, pentaho

I am using the variable path as `($..X..Y..Z)` , for i intend to pick values from path `X/Y/Z` , but instead I also get the values from all underlying paths where folder Z is present, such as `(X/Y/1/Z)`, `(X/Y/2/Z)`, `(X/Y/3/B/Z)`.

What should I do to get just the desired value and not any extra value ?

Comment: Not very sure. I would like to see the JSON document you are extracting the parameters from. But for X/Y/Z you can try $..X.Y.Z

Comment: Please post the JSON document and some example of your path and what are you trying to accomplish - attach [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably also screenshot of your transformation. I'm not even sure what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution lies in **Chaining the JSON input** steps of Pentaho. Simply go step by step, parse the first level of JSON and send the output to another JSON input step, in order to parse nested JSON data.

Please refer for worked example http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?198640-JSON-input-with-nested-structure-with-same-property-name-at-different-levels